# Cambiar el nombre de los registros en SQL

Tags: sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, Buenos días

Mi pregunta es: mediante una consulta SQL, como podría decirle que me cambie el nombre de los registros de la tabla label_code sin utilizar el Alias

Ejemplo practico; Cada letra pertenece a un color , existe alguna opción de decirle que todos los que sean con la letra M ponerle un alias de Magenta por ejemplo

PD: hay millones de registros por eso mencione sin utilizar el Alias por cada camp, seria una locura, seria mas fácil hacer todos los registros de la tabla label_code que compiencen por M ponte el Alias de Margenta

Alguien podría ayudarme con esta situación ?

Comment: Claro, dime si lo que quieres es actualizar cada registro (en vez de `M` actualizar a `Magenta`) o solo quieres "crear" otra columna con el campo actualizado?

Comment: Crear otra columna con el campo actualizado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el [UPDATE](http://sql.11sql.com/sql-update.htm)

Creando otra columna en la tabla con [ALTER TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-examples.html) o manual, puedes ejecutar esta consulta para `updatear` la nueva columna con la conversión de color de la columna `label_code`

```
UPDATE tu-tabla
SET columnaNueva = CASE 
                     WHEN label_code = 'M' THEN 'Magenta'
                     WHEN label_code = 'G' THEN 'Gris'
                     WHEN label_code = 'C' THEN 'Carmel'
                   ELSE
                     'Color no identificado'
                   END
```

O puedes hacerlo desde un `SELECT`

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN label_code = 'M' THEN 'Magenta'
         WHEN label_code = 'G' THEN 'Gris'
         WHEN label_code = 'C' THEN 'Carmel'
       ELSE
         'Color no identificado'
       END as color
FROM tu-table
```

Comment: Eso podría hacerlo si solo tengo permisos de DB de usuario ? (no soy admin )

Comment: al tener permisos de  usuario de DB, creo que no puedo ni crear nuevas tablas ni actualizar el valor de las tablas

Comment: Puedes ejecutarlo desde script

Comment: y entonces como quieres hacer para actualizar o crear en las tablas?

Comment: Cuando mencionas ejecutarlo desde Script a que te refieres exactamente ?podrías poner un ejemplo

Comment: Para actualizar o crear tablas, mas o menos allí estaba la pregunta, si es posible poner un Alias a todos los registros de la tabla "Labale_code" que empiecen por M = magenta , que empiecen por B = Blue ...etc

Comment: A ejecutarlo desde el panel de la BD (en SQL) pero bueno, puedes hacer una consulta, reemplazando el codigo por el nombre, ahora te actualizo mi respuesta.